# Packet Encoder GNU QPSK Transmission

Tags: digital-communications, gnuradio, qpsk

[image]

Hello everyone!.
This is a template to QPSK transmission but Packet Encoder block is no longer available in new GNURadio versions, what do I need to replace this block in order to do a QPSK Transmission? Or are there any newer examples?

Thanks in advance. Be safe

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/packet` (depending on your installation folder you might have to look i `/usr/local`)

`packet_tx` and `packe_rx` can be used as a replacement for Packet Encoder and Decoder. They are *Hierarchical Blocks* and can be generated and used as a  an whole block with a certain type of input and output.

`packet_loopback_hier` is a good example to check after you generate packet_tx and packet_rx.